# How to convert WEP key to ASCII passphrase?

Tags: c#, perl, networking, wifi, wep

Does anyone have a hex->ascii method to reverse the WEP encryption?

I have my WEP key (eg F2:E8:54:22:F3), but can't remember my passphrase.  I'm not too concerned with the accuracy of the passphrase.

I found [this site](http://my-software-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/04/get-passphrase-from-wep-key.html), which has a Linux program that seems to work with values of keys generated by [this site](http://www.netpoint.com/wep.htm) (supposedly the same WEP encryption engine), but unfortunately, it doesn't work with the key I have.

What I'd like is a Perl/C# solution if someone has one.

#### Things I realize:

1. I know there will be several ascii options, since this is WEP (the more the better, to help me find my original passphrase)
2. I know that WPA/WPA2 is suggested as a better alternative to WEP
3. I know that some routers have an http admin page (192.168.0.1), which may have the ascii passphrase there

#### Note:

1. I guess you could say this piggybacks on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247023/what-is-the-wep-shared-key-authentication-algorithm), but it's different since that one is asking about the authentication, whereas I'm more concerned with the WEP algorithm itself.
2. This is not for illegal hacking purposes.  Obtaining the WEP key would be illegal, since that is what's used in accessing a WEP-enforced network.  I'm merely asking how to convert that key to it's English alternative. - I should also note that accessing another person's network and using their resources w/o proper permission may be illegal.

Comment: What does the key look like, 10 or 26 hex digits?

Comment: Here's an example: (F2:E8:54:22:F3) - if you look at the comments from the first link, you'll see attempts.  It's a 64b key.

Answer (score 1):

it might be easier to just reset your router to its factory settings and resetting it up than to do  what you are attempting...

Comment: That's what I always did when I was in IT.

Comment: It's not always easier when you have a lot of devices/people that use the network (eg friends/family with phones or laptops, work devices that don't work well with at-home wifi networks, other OSes that are dormant and haven't been used in a while, game systems that suck at user input).  -- Your "reset the router" answer is is no better than "go buy a new router." Not only does it take a stab at my intelligence, but it's not a programming-minded solution, which Stack Overflow was set up to support.

Comment: Given your reply another consideration, resetting a router would only reset the login/password, which would leave me in a shitty position.  Having the WEP key right now and could still login with it.  The only problem is it is harder to remember the key down the road vs something a little more english-oriented.

Comment: I know I am a few years late, but I have to say: This is a horrible answer! It is less than useless since it makes others think this question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Every wireless network management interface I've ever dealt with has allowed me to enter the actual key (in hex) without requiring the English passphrase.  This is going to be your best bet.

You seem to already be aware (given your "Things I Realize" #1) that there is not a one-to-one mapping of WEP keys to English passphrases.  The reason for this is that the key is a non-reversible hash of the passphrase.  That being the case, unless there's a major flaw in the hashing algorithm (highly unlikely, given that I've never heard that listed among the litany of WEP's weaknesses), it is mathematically impossible to reverse the hash.

Since you can't compute the passphrase from the key, there are only two possible ways to do the conversion you're asking for:

1) Google the key and see whether it appears in any public WEP key rainbow tables.  However, given that there's extremely little actual value to an attacker in converting a WEP key back into a passphrase (they can just use the key directly, so why bother?), I would be mildly surprised if any such tables even exist.

2) Generate a crapload of candidate passphrases and throw them at WEP's hashing algorithm and hope that one of them generates the desired key.  While this will (eventually) work, it's almost certain to take longer than generating a new key and updating all affected devices unless you can remember enough of the previous passphrase to allow you to narrow the search space considerably.

Comment: I agree with everything said, however the point of all this is to remember what the passphrase was.  I can easily use the key to connect to the network, but it's not so easy to remember that key for new devices. -- it's also easier to tell friends with iPhones, `wi-fi pass is 'foobar99!'`, not `wi-fi pass is 'f2e85422f3'` :)

Comment: The link that I showed, does show that it's possible to reverse some keys.  Even if the results are not all correct, the phrase will either be mostly correct (at least 80%) or not event close.  Given the 80%, I could guess what the original phrase was, or I could make something up that also converts.  Example: if you reverse the key for `test`, you get `tesx` or exlamation sign gibberish.  Taking `tesx` I could guess that the passphrase was `test`.